# Changing Airdrop Folder

Tags: macos, finder, airdrop

I have changed the location of many other applications to save files to a custom folder instead of ~/Downloads.

Is there a way to change the default Airdrop location from the Downloads folder to something else?

Comment: It is 2022 and Apple Mac is still so difficult to use.

Answer (score 6):

I work for a school district and just had to do this.  The teacher receives student iMovie files for review, and I need to move this automatically from the Downloads folder to something else.

- Create the folder you want files moved to.
- I went into Automator (Applications folder) and created a new "Folder Action."
- At the top where it says "Folder Action receives files and folders added to" choose your Downloads folder.
- In Library (far left) choose Files and Folders, then Filter Finder Items.  Drag this to the workflow area to the right.  In my case, I added two criteria.  Kind is movie, and File extension contains m4v.
- Below "Filter Finder Items" drag Move Finder Items from the left side, and choose the new folder location.

That's it.  When someone airdrops a file that meets the criteria you set up, it should automatically move to the specified folder.  Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This is helpful however, i found myself not able to follow the last bit of instructions. Could you reproduce this for the most current OS version and take screenshots please?

Comment: great answer. It works with .jpg and .mov. But I'm finding that filtering on Kind = image or movie does not capture HEIF files. I tried filtering on file extension = HEIC but that does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: @rockhammer I'm seeing something similar with screen recordings I've taken. I can confirm by logging the filenames in the Folder Action. MOV and MP4 files are not printed when Kind is set to Movie, but only when AirDropped. When the files are moved from one directory to another, the Kind is evaluated correctly. This seems like an OS/AirDrop bug.

Answer (score 3):

Not easily, but you could enable Folder Actions on the Downloads folder before entering AirDrop and achieve the same effect on a more manual and case by case basis.

In practice it might be easier to change the other programs like Mail and Safari to not use the same default Downloads folder that AirDrop does have hard coded as the save point.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to change the default folder, but there does not appear to be a builtin way to do it. Therefore, I wrote an automator action that can be used in a folder action on your downloads folder. For example, I have one set to move any airdropped files to my Desktop. There is a binary for download at [my Github repository](https://github.com/mlilback/QuarantineAutomatorAction)

Comment: There's a video on this, but I gotta be honest. There are no instructions. The video points to a an automation file that I can't find. Would you mind updating the repo to have some instructions?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mark Lilbacks's Automator action (see his answer from June 2016), and I can't recommend it highly enough. It's the perfect solution.

https://github.com/mlilback/QuarantineAutomatorAction

Have created a dedicated Airdrops folder with a custom icon, which always goes to the bottom of my Download stack (set to Fan mode) when a new arrival appears.

Just DL the v0.1 Release, install the Action in Automator (with usual permissions - and caveats) and create a workflow. Works perfectly under High Sierra, though I can't comment on later OSs. Thanks Mark

(Newly registered here so can't comment or upvote yet)

Comment: You will need to provide a link or other easy way to get to this action, otherwise it is just someone's name which could lead you anywhere.

Comment: https://github.com/mlilback/QuarantineAutomatorAction 

"I wrote an automator action that can be used in a folder action on your downloads folder. For example, I have one set to move any airdropped files to my Desktop. There is a binary for download at my Github repository" Mark Lilback, 27 Jun'16

Comment: My answer clearly referenced an answer on this page which included the relevant the link. I was unable to quote the original reply in my own.
Anybody reading down the page should see Mark Lilback's answer first, including the link. (As I explained, as a newly registered member, I was unable to make my reply a comment to his answer, where it really belonged). 
Nonetheless the reply was edited as requested to add the link as requested, although duplicating a link already posted on this page by the creator of the Automator Action.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question (which has already been sufficiently addressed), but it could be a workaround for some people who need a quick fix.

I noticed that immediately after receiving an AirDrop download, all of the newly received files are selected for you. This means you can simply right-click on them and choose **New Folder with Selection**. You will then have all the items you just received, neatly organized in one place.

[image]

It just requires a bit of patience, waiting for the items to be transferred, and not clicking on any other items in Finder during the process (so as not to risk deselecting the ones you want to group together).

I know it's not the same as changing the default download location, but it's good to be aware of, just the same - especially since we don't always receive files on computers we have full permissions on. It's equally handy when transferring files to someone else too, if you instruct them to do this, or do it for them.

Answer (score 0):

For years I used my Desktop folder as the destination for downloads. Some apps allow changing that, others don't (like AirDrop).

It turns out it's so easy.

1. Open Automator
2. Select **Folder Action**

   [image: Choose a type for your Automator document: Folder Action]
3. Add the **Move Finder Items** action
4. Select the source and the destination

   [image: Completed Automator folder action to move downloads to desktop]
5. Save
6. Accept the permission request ✅

**Note:** This won't move files that already exist in that folder, if any. Move them out first.